# scrollable contents overlaps on fixed non-scrollable content

Tags: scrollbar

I want the scrollable part of the page to scroll within it's height only. But it overlaps with the header whose position has been set to 'fixed'.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3xc9n6jb/

How do I make them not overlap so that the scrollable content scrolls without touching the header?

```
<div class="main-div">
    <div class="myBox"></div> <!--This red rectangle is the header. The scrollable content should not overlap with this.-->
    <div class="scrollable-content horizontal">
        <ul>
            <li>First Item</li>
            <li>Second Item</li>
            <li>Third Item</li>
            <li>Fourth Item</li>
            <li>Fifth Item</li>
            <li>Sixth Item</li>
            <li>Seventh Item</li>
            <li>Eight Item</li>
            <li>Ninth Item</li>
            <li>Tenth Item</li>
        </ul>  
   </div>
</div>

.myBox {
    width: 500px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    position: fixed;
}

ul {
   position: absolute;
   margin-top: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want something like this:

```
  <div class="main-div">
<div class="myBox"></div> <!--This red rectangle is the header. The scrollable content should not overlap with this.-->
<div class="scrollable-content horizontal">
    <ul>
        <li>First Item</li>
        <li>Second Item</li>
        <li>Third Item</li>
        <li>Fourth Item</li>
        <li>Fifth Item</li>
        <li>Sixth Item</li>
        <li>Seventh Item</li>
        <li>Eight Item</li>
        <li>Ninth Item</li>
        <li>Tenth Item</li>
        <li>First Item</li>
        <li>Second Item</li>
        <li>Third Item</li>
        <li>Fourth Item</li>
        <li>Fifth Item</li>
        <li>Sixth Item</li>
        <li>Seventh Item</li>
        <li>Eight Item</li>
        <li>Ninth Item</li>
        <li>Tenth Item</li>
        <li>First Item</li>
        <li>Second Item</li>
        <li>Third Item</li>
        <li>Fourth Item</li>
        <li>Fifth Item</li>
        <li>Sixth Item</li>
        <li>Seventh Item</li>
        <li>Eight Item</li>
        <li>Ninth Item</li>
        <li>Tenth Item</li>
        <li>First Item</li>
        <li>Second Item</li>
        <li>Third Item</li>
        <li>Fourth Item</li>
        <li>Fifth Item</li>
        <li>Sixth Item</li>
        <li>Seventh Item</li>
        <li>Eight Item</li>
        <li>Ninth Item</li>
        <li>Tenth Item</li>
    </ul>
```

```
  .myBox {
    width: 500px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;

}

ul {
   margin-top: 50px;
}
```

the key is dont use `position:absolute` in `ul` selector and add the value of `margin-top` equals to `height` of `mybox`.

Comment: I appreciate you replying, but this will work only when you fix 'top: 0' for the header, which is not what I am looking for. This header and content can be on the middle of the page and in that case, the problem remains the same. @farhad goodarzi

Comment: maybe you want this:
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_affix.asp
this is affix